# Rails 3 Cache Returning Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails memory cache like this in one controller.

```
def form_config_cache
    Rails.cache.fetch("form_config", :expires_in => 12.hours) do
      puts 'Building cache...'
      form_config = s3_read_object('form_config.js')
      return JSON.parse(form_config)
    end
  end
```

This is working fine on the controller where it is defined. But when I try to read the value from another controller, it is returning as nil. Can anyone explain what might be going on? Here is how I am trying to read it in another controller.

```
form_config = Rails.cache.read('form_config')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually ever cache anything: `return` returns form the whole method, so the bit of `fetch` that stores values in the cache never executes and there is nothing for your call to `read` to return.

You could either use `next` or nothing at all:

```
def form_config_cache
  Rails.cache.fetch("form_config", :expires_in => 12.hours) do
    form_config = s3_read_object('form_config.js')
    JSON.parse(form_config)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for explaining. But need another explanation, I was using a log statement inside the cache block, and that was showing up only once, why did the cache block not execute every time, if nothing was being stored. I updated the code block to show where I was logging that statement.